# I wanna create a job search engine. How can i create an Apply button for each job that is displayed?

Tags: php, html

I wanna create a job search engine. So far i managed to store all the jobs throughout a form into mysql database and display them on my webpage. I wanna create an Apply button for each job that redirects the user to a form to write some information, but I dont know how to make the button to display different job names for example for each job.

I created a div for jobs that has the specific information for each one of them (name,department,location)

Picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbnQW.jpg    (i cant add directly since im new to the website)

How the button will know to display Junior for example if I press the one in the Junior accountant div ?

Here's the code for displaying the informations for each job in my webpage:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['job-search'])){

       $search=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['job-field']); //only string to not mess with db 
       $sql="SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobname LIKE '%$search%'";
       $result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       $resultcheck= mysqli_num_rows($result);

       if($resultcheck > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<div class='job-box'> 


             <p style ='color:gray;font-size:13px;padding-left:10%; padding-top:1%;'>"  . 'Posting date: ' .  $row['postingdate'] . "</p>
             <img src='image1.jpg' height='80px' width='80px'>
             <h4 style='color:bLACK;font-family:arial;font-size:15px;'>"  .  $row['jobname'] . "<br><br>" . $row['company'] . 
            " <form action='apply.php' method='POST'>
              <button style=width:80px;height:40px;float:right;margin-top:-42px;margin-right:40px;font-size:18px; id='applyjob'
              type='submit' name='apply' value=".$row['jobname']."> Apply </button></form>" . "</h4><br><br>
             <p style='border-top:2px solid black;'><br>" . "<img src='image2.jpg'; height='18px' width='15px'>". "&nbsp;   " . $row['town'] . "</p><br>
             <p>"  . "<img src='image6.png'; height='18px' width='15px'>". "&nbsp;  "  . $row['experience'] . "</p> <br>
             <p>"   . "<img src='image5.jpg'; height='18px' width='15px'>". "&nbsp; "  . $row['jobtype'] . "</p> <Br>
             <p>"   .  "<img src='image8.jpg'; height='18px' width='15px'>". "&nbsp; "  . $row['department'] . "</p> <br>
             <p id='mobile' style='font-size:25px;font-family:cambria;'>Job description</p>
             <p id='mobile' style='height:100px;width:91%;text-align:justify;overflow-x:hidden; color:gray; line-height:20px;'>"   . nl2br($row['decription']) . "</p> 





          </div> <br><br><br>"; 
            }

       } else {
           echo 'No results found.';
       }


}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem you have? You can create a button in HTML with `<button>` or something like `<input type="submit" />`. Why do you not do that here as well? What is the problems you get?

Comment: The problem is that I want the user when pressing the button to see the name of the specific job that he applied for in a read only input on another webpage and i want the button to know what exactly what job name to retrieve in that field

Comment: You have to send the ID of the row from the `jobs` table to the new page. That way you can load all the information from that specific job entry and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have a field in your jobs for telling if its junior, senior, etc for example "level".. then add

```
<button value=".$row['level'].">
```

Comment: i think u are refering to a column in the jobs table ? If that's so, I already have it under the name jobname. I'm gonna try this and see what do i get. Thanks for comment

Comment: im still working on the layout of the page, when is done im gonna try and let you know if it worked. I posted the question very early so I can get multiple answers and try them all if needed.

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: how are you adding the button?

Comment: i updated the code and the image. In the "apply.php" I want to retrieve de job name after pressing the button, im not quite sure how to do that, i tryed with (isset($_POST['apply']))

Comment: well, if you want to recieve the job name in another php file.. you can make the button a link and pass the ID of the job by url.. as follow  `<a href="url/".$row['id']."><button>LINK</button></a>` and then in the other php file  `$id = $_GET['id']`.. now you can query for all the data of the job selected

Comment: got it figured out, thanks for help man, you're the best! Cheers!